# Adding @Aspect throws BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am trying to use AOP in Spring. When I am using old DTD methods in XML, things are working fine. But when I am trying to use `AspectJ` notations, I am facing some issues. I downloaded the JAR files for aspectj from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/aspectjrt/). I added them to the build path and the code containing `@Aspect` annotations compiled successfully. But during runtime, nothing is getting executed. Even the beans which are using XML based configuration for aspects, are not getting created. It is throwing some `BeanCreationException`. The full error log is as follows:

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emp1' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'emp1' defined in class path resource [Beans.xml]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:512)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:85)
    at com.demo.Tester.main(Tester.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/aspectj/weaver/reflect/ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getPointcut(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:210)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvisor(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.getAdvisors(ReflectiveAspectJAdvisorFactory.java:126)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.buildAspectJAdvisors(BeanFactoryAspectJAdvisorsBuilder.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.annotation.AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.findCandidateAdvisors(AnnotationAwareAspectJAutoProxyCreator.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.autoproxy.AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.shouldSkip(AspectJAwareAdvisorAutoProxyCreator.java:101)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:251)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1141)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.resolveBeforeInstantiation(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:506) ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.aspectj.weaver.reflect.ReflectionWorld$ReflectionWorldException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Can someone help me out in finding out what is the error? I am understanding that the JVM is unable to find out the `@Aspect` annotation somehow, but why is it happening even after adding the JAR file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a strange web site for downloading JARs there. I recommend not to download dependency JARs manually but to use a build tool like Maven to take care of that for you. Anyway, if you want to make your life as a developer harder, you can do it manually. You can search for and download dependencies here:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.aspectj/aspectjweaver

Just search, select the version you need and then download.

The reason for your problem is that, guessing by your link URL, you downloaded the AspectJ runtime library `aspectjrt.jar`, but that one is the smallest one there is and meant to be used with ApsectJ compile-time weaving. You are using Spring AOP, which depends on the AspectJ load-time weaving library `aspectjweaver.jar`. Put that one on your classpath, then your error should go away. BTW, the weaver library contains a superset of the runtime classes, so you do not need the runtime anymore in this case.

I also recommend to read some more documentation. The Spring manual tells you to use the weaver, not the runtime, see chapter [Enabling @AspectJ Support](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#aop-aspectj-support).